# (Reference request) How to show elliptic curve has positive Mordell-Weil rank

Tags: elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I know there must be a lot of ways to show an elliptic curve has positive Mordell-Weil rank if it really does. And I guess that I am supposed to collect them by myself. But since I am not working in this area, I hope there are some people tell me the important methods that I should not miss and the corresponding reference.

Appreciate for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The surest way of proving an elliptic curve over $\Bbb Q$ has
positive rank is to write down an element of infinite order.
By the [Lutz-Nagell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagell%E2%80%93Lutz_theorem) each point of finite order
on an elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ ($a,b,c\in\Bbb Z$) has
integer coordinates. So if you can find a point on the curve
with non-integer rational coordinates, the curve must have positive rank.

Comment: Thanks @Lord Shark the Unknown. Do you know an effective way to find at least one rational point of an elliptic curve? (Assume that curve has at least one such point).

Comment: @LeoD That's the hard part...

Answer (score 1):

There several methods to show an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ has positive rank (so infinitely many points), even without giving a point of infinite order.

The easiest way for a specific elliptic curve is to use either pari, sage or magma, asking either for the rank, or for the analytic rank; if this analytic rank is zero or 1, then it is equal to the actual rank this is a theorem by Kolyvagin).

There are also conjectural ways to show an elliptic curve has positive rank: if you compute the so-called root number (which pari, sage or magma does very fast) and it is $-1$, then the parity conjecture asserts your curve has odd rank (so positive).

The bibliography concerning all this is quite bast; without knowing what do you want to know exactly it is difficult to point you to some specific place.